# javax.sql.DataSource Can not resolve symbol

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, datasource

When I am javax.sql.DataSource class in my code I am getting can not resolve symbol error. My java version is jdk1.3.1. Please help me..

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
public class DBConnectionManager
{
  public synchronized Connection getConnection(String s)
  {
    try
    {
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource)pools.get(s);
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlexception)
    {
        log(sqlexception, "SQL In getConnection for pool " + s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is throwing the error?

Comment: @nolt This is just an sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc states that that class is implemented since java 1.4, if you compile against 1.3.1 then I can understand why it throws that error..

[DataSource javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html)

Comment: Thanks. I dint to see 1.4 also installed in system. I wasted lot of time by checking code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

add:
requires java.sql;
in module-info.java